# Is there a distinction between 怎样 (zěnyàng) and 怎么样 (zěnmeyàng)?

Tags: usage, difference

**Question**: Is there a distinction between 怎样 (zěnyàng) and 怎么样 (zěnmeyàng)?

At first, 怎样 seems like a shortened version of 怎么样.  However, let's look at some Jukuu.com examples for [怎样](http://jukuu.com/show-%E6%80%8E%E6%A0%B7.html):

> 你知道**怎样**处理这个问题吗？
> Do you know how to deal with this problem?
> <sub>(Nǐ zhīdào zěnyàng chǔlǐ zhège wèntí ma?)</sub>
>
> 你们今年是**怎样**庆祝五一节的？
> How did you celebrate May Day this year?
> <sub>(Nǐmen jīnnián shì zěnyàng qìngzhù wǔyī jié de?)</sub>

And for [怎么样](http://jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%80%8E%E4%B9%88%E6%A0%B7)：

> 这些日子你**怎么样**？
> How are you doing these days?
> <sub>(Zhèxiē rìzi nǐ zěnme yàng?)</sub>
>
> 他法语学得**怎么样**了？
> How is he coming on with his study of French?
> <sub>(Tā fǎyǔ xué dé zěnme yàngle?)</sub>

It seems the usage is different between the two.  I asked a Chinese friend about it and he indicated they're mostly similar, but there's a difference in usage.  I didn't fully understand though.

---

<sub>(PS. This is not a duplicate of [What is the difference between 怎么 and 怎么样 ？](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/22871/8099) because that question asks about 怎么, not 怎样.)</sub>

Comment: bkrs: entry for 怎样  says см. (see) 怎么样

Comment: comments 2,4,5,6 of  https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22871/what-is-the-difference-between-%e6%80%8e%e4%b9%88-and-%e6%80%8e%e4%b9%88%e6%a0%b7  have excerpt from grammar＂实用现代汉语语法＂ explaining ＂怎么＂、＂怎么样＂、＂怎样＂

Comment: @user6065 What is "см"?

Comment: abbreviation of “смотреть”, Russian for “see”

Comment: ＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂also has entry regarding 怎么／怎样／怎么样，below only find the parts regarding difference between 怎样 and 怎么样:  **［不同]**  ４。＂怎么、怎么样＂可以单独成句，用在句子前面，但不能互换：＂怎么＂表示没想到、惊讶，＂怎么样＂表示追问或得意的语气：＂怎样＂不能单独样在句子前面：（１）怎么？李红还没和你说吗？（怎么样✗怎样✗）（２）怎么？你不想去了？（怎么样✗怎样✗）（３）怎么？他竟然不同意？（怎么样✗怎样✗）（４）怎么样？他到底行不行？（怎么✗怎样✗）（５）怎么样？时间定下来没有？（怎么✗怎样✗）（６）怎么样？我就说我一定能赢的！（怎么✗怎样✗）
５。＂怎么样＂可以单独成句，用在句子后，询问对方的意见；＂怎么、怎样＂不能：（１）我们今天就去，怎么样？（怎样✗怎么✗）（２）我们去打篮球，怎么样？（怎样✗怎么✗）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are completely interchangeable.

I would probably say their effects are a **very little bit** different, (which people indeed wouldn't care most of time).

怎样做 vs 怎么样做， the longer version(the latter) sounds like it might engage a bit more procedures or processes than the shorter version(the former).

Again, that's just an effect, which couldn't be even a matter in practice.

Answer (score 0):

In the first two examples for 怎样, it's totally OK to use 怎么样 instead.

In 他法语学得怎么样了, also you can use 怎样 instead.

这些日子你怎么样 seem to be an exception, where using 怎样 feels a bit unnatural, though acceptable still. I think it's because 怎么样 serves as a verb in this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

There are no difference in meaning.
怎样 is written and 怎么样 is spoken, though sometimes it doesn't matter.